AO Maps stretch?
Not sure how to word this problem, but when I bake my AO Maps its like they extend outwards. Is there a way to avoid this? 

Please provide more informations on your setup. And https://blend-exchange.com/

Hello and welcome. Does not look like a problem, it looks more like texture dilation
